# Which design pattern should I use?

Tags: c#, .net, design-patterns

I have the following code which executes in sequence, method after another.

I load the request, perform a couple of checks like checking if a response already exists for this request, if not, I call the service and receive the response which I save to the DB.

I was looking for a design pattern I can use in such a case, I thought of posting this here and get some ideas.

```
public class Manager
    {

        public void PutRequest()
        {
            //Do Something

            if (loadRequest())
            {
                  callService(); 

                  //Do Something
                  saveResponse();
            }

        }

        private bool loadRequest()
        {            
             bool isExist = checkIfResponseExists();

             if (!isExist)
             {
              // If false, load request from DB
             } 

             return !isExist;

        }

        private bool checkIfDataExists()
        {
            //Check if a response already exists in the DB for this request
        }

        private void callService()
        {
            //Call the service and receive the response
        }    

        private void saveResponse()
        {
            //Store the response in the DB
        }

    }
```

Comment: Why are you using `method2()` since it calls `method3()`? What about calling `method3()` immediately? :)

Comment: Wait.... aren't all of those properties? :P

Comment: Method2 loads the request from DB if method3 returns false. These are really a small scaled version of the code, there are more methods and more code. I am just trying to clarify what I meant by saying that the code executes in sequence.

Comment: Before considering patterns, start by naming your methods with meaningful names. This code is completely unreadable. And every line of code must not participate in a pattern. You simply have a sequence of operations, and there's not much to do except executing them in sequence.

Comment: @JeffBridgman I do not think so. These are called voids, voids may execute a code block for the programmer when the void is called. For example, if you say `method2();`, this will execute the code under `method2`. Have a great day and I hope you find this helpful :)

Comment: Oh okay, I was under the impression that `void` was required... errr, wait a second... `void` wasn't there when I posted that comment, I promise! ;)

Comment: Jeff, and JB This is just an example in order to help clarifying my point. I totally agree on having meaningful names for variable and functions

Comment: @JeffBridgman You are right! The question was edited!

Comment: @JeffBridgman I just modified it to avoid confusion and gave you +1 :)

Comment: I replaced the methods names with something meaningful, but I am not asking about this exact code, my question is "what is the best pattern to use for code that executes sequentially like the one above?"

Comment: Why do you pass isExist via a private variable?  Return that status from loadRequest().

Comment: There is no pattern for this kind of code. What you have is just fine, except for the instance boolean variable, which should not exist and be returned by `loadReqest()`. You just have a sequence of operations.

Comment: This code might do well on codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: You might want to look into [Workflow Patterns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Workflow_patterns), but it depends on your situation. If it is just a thought about what pattern you could use... Well, read the link I gave or just keep it simple (and call the methods in sequence).

Comment: BostonPharaoh - do you have a situation where you need to implement the same process for different types of requests?

Answer (score 1):

Patterns are used for solving some problems. What problem your current code have? I don't see any duplicated code, beside names of methods. There is no pattern, which fixes method naming problem.

Yes, your code need some refactoring, but not to patterns. Better class and method naming is a first step. Also, I'd removed field `isExist`.

```
public class Manager
{
   public void PutRequest()
   {
       //Do Something
       if (!CheckIfResponseExists()) // returns boolean value
            LoadRequestFromDB()

        CallService(); 
        //Do Something
        SaveResponse();
   }
}
```

Comment: I replaced the methods names with something meaningful, but I am not asking about this exact code, my question is "what is the best pattern to use for code that executes sequentially like the one above?"

Answer (score 0):

Check the design pattern called Strategy, it defines an interface common to all supported algorithms and each concrete strategy implements an algorithm

http://www.oodesign.com/strategy-pattern.html

Answer (score 0):

It seems like it'd be more useful for several of these methods to be functions. So instead of having a method who's responsibility is to both check for a condition and do some other actions, you have a function that checks for a condition then the method that called it does some action depending on the result. (Kind of the [SRP](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?SingleResponsibilityPrinciple) applied to methods...)

```
public void DoAllTheThings!() // Oops, Ruby syntax creeping in :P
{
   if(!WeCanDoIt())
   {
     MakeItSo(); // So that we can do it...
   }

   NowWeCanDoAllTheThings();
}

private bool WeCanDoIt() {}
private void MakeItSo() {}
private void NowWeCanDoAllTheThings() {}
```

Answer (score 0):

Command + Composite.

Some people consider the use of an if/then Command - in your case that would be in putRequest - in a Composite a kind of Chain Of Responsibility.

Answer (score 0):

While selecting a pattern you should consider scalability of the application

One of the pattern you can apply is **state** pattern

There will be two states.

1. Response is already there
2. Need to process the new response